# React mapping rendering issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, array.prototype.map

I'm having a very perplexing issue that I wonder if anyone could help with. I have objects being mapped as arrays into some html(/jsx). The objects aren't rendering. Strangely, though, in the debugger it does show each value being attributed to the insertions in the html -- but it's not rendering. any ideas?

The picture below is an example of one object in the `reservations` array showing as mapping in the debugger, whereas the rendering actually stays as the second picture.

The `axios` http request, in a promise with another request:

```
const getReservations = 
   axios
      .get(`${api_url}/reservations`, {
          headers: {
              'Authorization': `Bearer ${sessionStorage.token}`
          }
       })
       .then((res) => {
           setReservations(reservations => ([...reservations, ...res.data]));
       })
        
const getRoomTypes = 
   axios
       .get(`${api_url}/room-types`, {
           headers: {
               'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': `${ui_url}`,
               'Authorization': `Bearer ${sessionStorage.token}`
           }
       })
       .then((res) => {
           setRoomTypes(roomTypes => ([...roomTypes, ...res.data]));
       })
        
Promise.all([getReservations, getRoomTypes])
    .catch(() => { 
         setError(connectionError);
    });

}, []);
```

Which passes the data to the rendered component:

```
return (
   <div>
     <h2>Reservations</h2>
     <Link className="button" to="/reservations/create">Create</Link>
     <br />
     <br />
     <ReservationDiv error={error} resData={reservations} />
   </div>
);
```

The component in  which the objects are rendered:

```
const ReservationDiv = (props) => {
    
    const reservations = props.resData;

    const renderTableData = () => {
        reservations.map((reservation) => {
            const { id, user, guestEmail, roomTypeId, checkInDate, 
                    numberOfNights } = reservation;
            
    return (
       <tr key={id}>
          <td className="res">{id}</td>
          <td className="user">{user}</td>
          <td className="email">{guestEmail}</td>
          <td className="room">{roomTypeId}</td>
          <td className="date">{checkInDate}</td>
          <td className="nights">{numberOfNights}</td>
       </tr>
      );
  });
}

   return (
       <table>
           <tbody>
               <tr>
                   <th>ID</th>
                   <th>Input by</th>
                   <th>Guest Email</th>
                   <th>Room Type</th>
                   <th>Check-in Date</th>
                   <th># of Nights</th>
                   <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
                {renderTableData()}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
```

[image]

[image]

I can also provide quoted code, but I figured the problem seems to be something more fundamental, since it's a difference between a representation of a thing and the thing itself

Comment: I would make sure you post the full react component since it's not clear whether you're rendering this object. You may just be iterating over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` the mapped array of JSX objects

```
const renderTableData = () => {
    return reservations.map((reservation) => {
//...
```